# Sharing wireless LAN via ethernet

Tags: windows-server-2008

```
 +------------+           +------------+
 |            | Ethernet  |            |
 |  Client-A  |<----+---->|  Server    |
 |            |           |            |
 +------------+           +------------+
                                +
                                |
                       Wireless |
                                |
                                |
 +------------+                 v
 |            |  Wireless   +--------+
 |  Client-B  |+----------->|Router  |
 |            |             +--------+
 +------------+                 +
                                |
                                v
                            Internet
```

;This is my network topology.

Plan A: The server can share internet access with Client-A but Client-A can not access Client-B's shared folders without specifically entering the clients' local IP address. Is it possible to give Client-A access to Client-B using B's hostname?

Plan B: Connect Client-A to the wireless directly, not via Server. Everything works as expected except when sharing files between Client-A and Server it sometimes uses the ethernet connection (as intended) and sometimes the wireless connection (not intended, very slow). Is is possible to force sharing over ethernet only (hence the birth of plan a).

```
Additional info:
Client-A: Win7
Server: 2008
Ethernet: 10.0.0.1and2/255.0.0.0
Wireless: 192.168.1.1xx/255.255.255.0
Router: Netgear WNR3500L w/Tomato
```

Comment: I was going to give an answer to Plan B as well, but I wasn't sure of the IP topology there.  When CLient-A is connected to wireless and ethernet, is it in 192.168.1.0 twice, or once in 10.0.0.0 and once in 192.168.1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan A) As your server is 2008, you could run AD on it, and so have a common directory.  Or you could run DNS on it.  Or you could just bridge the Ethernet and Wireless network cards on the 2008 server, and use a single network without routing.  So everything would then be in 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: Bridge works. Tried it before also but think I forgot to manually specify the router's subnet.